# Save Using Ajax And Include Notice - Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I've added :remote => true to the _form.html.erb and wondered now how I can get it so when the user saves what's on the page, it saves and then comes up with a notice.

In my documents_controller.rb, I have;

```
def create
  @document = current_user.documents.build(params[:document])

  if @document.save
    redirect_to @document.edit, notice: 'Saved'
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end

def update
  @document = current_user.documents.find_by_url_id(params[:id])

  if @document.update_attributes(params[:document])
    redirect_to @document, notice: 'Saved'
  else
    render action: "edit"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write the appropriate JavaScript to make use of the following jQuery events:

```
ajax:beforeSend
ajax:complete
ajax:success
ajax:error
```

E.g.

```
$(document).ready(
    $(".ajax_rails_link").bind("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr){
        console.log(data);

        // Display your notice logic goes here
    })
});
```

More information can be found here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html